# execute awk linux command with php

Tags: php, linux

i want to execute a awk linux command with php , the command is

```
 mpstat | awk '$12 ~ /[0-9.]+/ { print 100 - $12 }'
```

i eexcute it wiht linux it works , its gave me the cpu usage in presentage, i try this in php:

```
$cmd= system("mpstat | awk '$12 ~ /[0-9.]+/ { print 100 - $12 }'",$retval);
echo $retval;
```

and

```
$cmd= passthru(" mpstat | awk '$12 ~ /[0-9.]+/ { print 100 - $12 }'",$retval);
 echo $retval;
```

its not working , i do some searches about it so i put the awk command in variable then execute it :

```
$var='$12 ~ /[0-9.]+/ { print 100 - $12 }';
$cmd=  exec('mpstat | awk"$var"',$retval);
echo $retval;
```

and the output is always  `Array`

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a short program to illustrate the difference:

```
<?php
$cmd = system("ls", $retval);
echo "Cmd: " . $cmd . "\n";
echo "Retval: " . $retval . "\n";
?>
```

output:

```
prog.php
Cmd: prog.php
Retval: 0
```

Comment: what difference you mean ?

Comment: He means the difference between a command's output and its return status.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use [popen](https://www.php.net/popen) for these purposes.

Example:

```
$handle = popen('mpstat | awk \'$12 ~ /[0-9.]+/ { print 100 - $12 }\' 2>&1', 'r');
$read = fread($handle, 8192);
var_dump($read);
pclose($handle);
```

Comment: how can i use popen , with this example ?

Comment: `popen` returns a resource that can be openned with `fopen`. To read the contents, it's just like a regular file, you will do it with `fread`.

Comment: can you do it with example above? i am a biggner with php :)

Comment: Notice that you should use single quotes or, if use double quotes, unescape the inner single quotes and escape the `$` characters inside the awk pattern.